# How to insert nested objects into MongoDB with Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I'm using Laravel 5 and MongoDB based Eloquent Jenssegers to develop an API to save and get data. I have a object called Player and inside I have other nested objects.

For example:

```
{
  "idPlayer": "1",
  "name": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "stats": {
    "position": "lorem",
    "profile": "ipsum",
    "technique": {
      "skill": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Using Postman to test I've could insert `"idPlayer"`, `"name"` and `"lastname"` without problems, but I couldn't figure out how to insert stats inside the Player object.

This is what I've tried:

PlayerController.php

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $player->name= $request->input('name');
    $player->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
    $player->save();
    return response()->json($player);
}
```

And to insert stats I've tried to do something like this inside the store function:

```
$player->stats = $request->input('position');
$player->stats = $request->input('profile');
```

But I get `"Stats:null"` on response and the name and lastname inserts ok.

I expect to insert the data just as the `Player` object shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array with keys.

```js
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $player->name = $request->input('name');
    $player->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
    $player->stats = [
      'position' => $request->input('stats.position'),
      'profile' => $request->input('stats.profile'),
    ];
    $player->save();
    return response()->json($player);
}
```

- More data about [PHP arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).
- Retrieving input from [Laravel Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it show Stats, but the attributes inside are null. It's like it can't read the position and profile.

Comment: Opps, you need to use `stats.position` to get the data. See here for more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: Ohh, I see, thank you very much. I get confused because in PHP the dot concatenates. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround solution for Laravel.MongoDB:

```php
$user = Player::firstOrCreate(['email' => strtolower($email)]);
$user->stats = array_merge( (array) $user->stats ?? [], ['key'=>'val']);
```

This will create `stats` attribute if not exists or append in existing.