# Eloquent - inserting related models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159277/how-to-insert-nested-objects-into-mongodb-with-laravel-5) the accepted answer to saving related models was:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $player->name = $request->input('name');
    $player->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
    $player->stats = [
      'position' => $request->input('stats.position'),
      'profile' => $request->input('stats.profile'),
    ];
    $player->save();
    return response()->json($player);
}
```

Whenever I try this I get an error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stats' in 'field
>   list'

If I add stats to the guarded collection, it of course never comes in.

On my player object I have this:

```
public function stats(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Stat::class);
}
```

So how can I have my stats come in, but elqoquent not attempt to use 'stats' as a column name in the insert?

Comment: its not inserting in related models. it just adding an array/json column in the object. check this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) to save related model.

Comment: Thanks, I have read that and it mentions pulling an object from the db, adding related objects to it, then pushing it. I couldn't find that it addressed my situation, where I'm creating the parent and children together, which is what it appears the answer I linked to does with `$player->save()`

Comment: no, you are getting it wrong. the answer you linked are only working with a single object. and you need two. check out the answer provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `save()` method, you can create a new `Player` object and save it, and then create a new `Stat` object and save it as a `Player` related `stats()`:

```
$player = new Player
$player->name = $request->input('name');
$player->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
$player->save();

$stat = new Stat([
    'position' => $request->input('stats.position'),
    'profile' => $request->input('stats.profile'),
]);
$player->stats()->save($stat);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, though I'm still confused by the answer to the question I linked to as it appears to suggest it can be done all in one step. (which is what I'm used to with Entity Framework in .net projects)

Comment: Well, no, to create the related stat you'll need the player `id`, so you have to insert the player in DB to it have an `id`. I think you can do it in one line using the `create()` method and chaining the related stat `create` to the the player `create`. But the same, you must always insert the player first.